# SystemVerilog array random seed of Shuffle function

Tags: system-verilog

I get the same output everytime I run the code below.

```
module array_shuffle;
   integer data[10];

   initial begin
      foreach (data[x]) begin
         data[x] = x;
      end

      $display("------------------------------\n");
      $display("before shuffle, data contains:\n");

      foreach (data[x]) begin
         $display("data[%0d] = %0d", x, data[x]);
      end

      data.shuffle();
      $display("------------------------------\n");
      $display("after shuffle, data contains:\n");

      foreach (data[x]) begin
         $display("data[%0d] = %0d", x, data[x]);
      end

   end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
------------------------------

before shuffle, data contains:

data[0] = 0
data[1] = 1
data[2] = 2
data[3] = 3
data[4] = 4
data[5] = 5
data[6] = 6
data[7] = 7
data[8] = 8
data[9] = 9
------------------------------

after shuffle, data contains:

data[0] = 8
data[1] = 6
data[2] = 7
data[3] = 9
data[4] = 5
data[5] = 0
data[6] = 1
data[7] = 4
data[8] = 2
data[9] = 3
```

Is there a way to seed the randomization of the shuffle function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shuffle returns the same result every time because you probably run the simulator with the same seed. This is the intended behavior, because when you run a simulation and find a bug, you want to be able to reproduce it, regardless of any design (and to some extent testbench) changes. To see a different output, try setting the seed on the simulator command line. For Incisive this is:

```
irun -svseed 1    // sets the seed to 1
irun -svseed random   // will set a random seed
```

It's also possible to manipulate the seed of the random number generator using set_randstate, but I wouldn't mess with that.

Comment: This is a vendor specific solution though I think there is no standard way.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. All simulators have a mechanism to control the seed from the command line. The random values that get generated based on that seed will be vendor specific, for sure, as the standard does not explicitly define an implementation of the randomization engine.